# Hide div with match ID and Class Using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want hide div which has id 'hide' and class 'test'. It is working fine with `.filter` method but I want to is there another method to do this. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cmqv/)

```
if($('#hide').hasClass('test')){
   $('.test').hide();
}
```

or

```
$('#hide').filter(function(){
   return this.className=='test'
}).hide();
```

Comment: The ID attribute is unique in a page, so its should suffice as a selector. also, its for simple hiding purposes (without special animations), add **display: none;** to a **#hide.test** rule in CSS, no need for Script.

Comment: @avrahamcool Yes, but that element may have different states (ie. classes, attributes etc.) that you might want to check against. Adding them to the selector as on PSL's answer is an efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write it as

```
$('#hide.test').hide();
```

no space between selectors will select the element which has id `hide` and class `test`

Not quite clear on what you meant by dynamic but as @kolink said you can just concatinate them. If there are many classnames in an array you could even do.

```
var toHide = ["hide", "if", "allarepresent"];
$("#hide." + toHide.join('.')).hide();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgYQp/)**

Comment: +1 for adding the comment about "no space" - so many people seem unaware of how to apply two selectors to the same element :D

Comment: But what if class is generating dynamicly

Comment: @amit You can concatenate: `$("#hide."+classToTest)`